# How to integrate $\frac{1}{(x+1)(x+2)^2(x+3)^3}$?

Tags: calculus, integration

I tried to solve it with partial fraction decomposition but the expression becomes way too difficult to solve. I could only solve three of six(A-F) expressions of the partial fraction expansion.

Comment: Making the substitution $u = x+2$ might make the problem a little more manageable.

Comment: I tried doing the substitution and it didn't get me any further.

Comment: **Hint:**  Use partial fractions (the final result is likely to involve $\arctan$ and/or $\ln$.

See [this][1].


  [1]: https://www.math24.net/integration-rational-functions/

Comment: The $\frac{A}{x+1}, \frac{C}{(x+2)^2}, \frac{F}{(x+3)^3}$ terms are easy to solve. For the rest of the partial fractions, I finished by solving a linear system of three equations in three unknowns for $B, D, E$ by arbitrarily substituting in easy values for $x$, such as $x = 0, 1, 2$.

Answer (score 4):

$\frac{1}{(x+1)(x+2)^2(x+3)^3} = \frac {A}{x+1} + \frac {B}{x+2} + \frac {C}{(x+2)^2} + \frac {D}{x+3} + \frac {E}{(x+3)^2} + \frac F{(x+3)^3} $

Here is a little trick.

Multiply trough by $(x+1)$

$\frac{(x+1)}{(x+1)(x+2)^2(x+3)^3} = A + \frac {B}{x+2}(x+1) + \frac {C}{(x+2)^2}(x+1) + \frac {D}{x+3}(x+1) + \frac {E}{(x+3)^2}(x+1) + \frac F{(x+3)^3}(x+1) $

And take the limit as x approaches $-1$

$\lim_\limits{x\to -1} \frac{(x+1)}{(x+1)(x+2)^2(x+3)^3} = \frac {1}{(1^2)(2^3)} = \frac 18 = A$

We can do something similar to quickly find $C, F$

$\lim_\limits{x\to -2} \frac{(x+2)^2}{(x+1)(x+2)^2(x+3)^3} =  C$

$\lim_\limits{x\to -3} \frac{(x+3)^3}{(x+1)(x+2)^2(x+3)^3} = F$

That leaves B, D, E

Multiplying through by $(x+2)^2$  and simplifying the LHS

$\frac{1}{(x+1)(x+3)^3} = \frac {A}{x+1}(x+2)^2 + B(x+2) + C + \frac {D}{x+3}(x+2)^2 + \frac {E}{(x+3)^2}(x+2)^2 + \frac F{(x+3)^3}(x+2)^2$

If we take the derivative of both sides and take the limits of as x approaches $- 2$

$\lim_\limits{x\to -2}\frac {d}{dx}\frac{1}{(x+1)(x+3)^3} =  B\\
\lim_\limits{x\to -2}\frac{- 3(x+1) - (x+3)^3}{(x+1)^2(x+3)^4} =  B\\
2 =  B$

$\lim_\limits{x\to -3}\frac {d}{dx}\frac{1}{(x+1)(x+2)^2} =  E$

And we take a second derivative to find $D$

$\lim_\limits{x\to -3}\frac {d^2}{dx^2}\frac{1}{(x+1)(x+2)^2} =  2D$

Answer (score 3):

Following @paulinho's suggestion, we want to write $\frac{1}{u^2(u-1)(u+1)^3}$ as a sum of partial fractions. The rest we can build by repeatedly using how to write the reciprocal of a quadratic with partial fractions. Note that $$\frac{1}{(u-1)(u+1)}=\frac12\left(\frac{1}{u-1}-\frac{1}{u+1}\right)\\\implies\frac{1}{(u-1)(u+1)^2}=\frac14\left(\frac{1}{u-1}-\frac{1}{u+1}-\frac{2}{(u+1)^2}\right)\\\implies\frac{1}{(u-1)(u+1)^3}=\frac18\left(\frac{1}{u-1}-\frac{1}{u+1}-\frac{2}{(u+1)^2}-\frac{4}{(u+1)^3}\right)\\\implies\frac{1}{u^2(u-1)(u+1)^3}=\frac18\left(\frac{1}{u^2(u-1)}-\frac{1}{u^2(u+1)}-\frac{2}{u^2(u+1)^2}-\frac{4}{u^2(u+1)^3}\right).$$You can do the rest yourself with such observations as$$\frac{1}{u^2(u\pm 1)}=\pm\frac{1}{u}\left(\frac{1}{u}-\frac{1}{u\pm 1}\right)=\pm\frac{1}{u^2}\mp\frac{1}{u}\pm\frac{1}{u\pm 1},\\\frac{1}{u^2(u+1)^2}=\frac{1}{u^2}-\frac{2}{u}+\frac{2}{u+1}+\frac{1}{(u+1)^2}.$$

Answer (score 3):

The substitution
$$x=-\left( 3+\frac{2}{u} \right)$$
reduces the integral to

$$\begin{align}
  & =\frac{1}{8}\int{\frac{{{u}^{4}}}{\left( u+1 \right){{\left( u+2 \right)}^{2}}}du} \\ 
 & =\frac{1}{8}\int{u-5+\frac{17{{u}^{2}}+36u+20}{\left( u+1 \right){{\left( u+2 \right)}^{2}}}du} \\ 
 & =\frac{1}{8}\int{u-5+\frac{1}{u+1}+\frac{16}{u+2}-\frac{16}{{{\left( u+2 \right)}^{2}}}du} \\ 
\end{align}$$

and you can see that partial fraction decomposition becomes much easier.

Answer (score 2):

When partial fraction decomposition becomes a bit overwhelming, you can apply the Horowitz-Ostrogradsky algorithm ! [*Manuel Bronstein - Symbolic Integration I*]

It is very mechanical, only the calculation of $H$ is tedious, but the rest is quite easy.

So we start with $$\frac AD=\frac{1}{(x+1)(x+2)^2(x+3)^3}$$

$A=1$

$D=(x+1)(x+2)^2(x+3)^3$

$D\,'=(x+2)(x+3)^2(6x^2+22x+18)$

$D^-=\gcd(D,D\,')=(x+2)(x+3)^2$

$D^*=D/D^-=(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)$

$B=\sum_{i=0}^{\deg(D^-)-1}b_ix^i=b_0+b_1x+b_2x^2$

$C=\sum_{i=0}^{\deg(D^*)-1}c_ix^i=c_0+c_1x+c_2x^2$

And let's identify to the null polynomial $$\forall x:\quad H(x)=A-B\,'D^*+BD^*{D^{-}}'/D^--CD^-=0$$

$H(x)=-c_2x^5+(b_2-c_1-8c_2)x^4+(2b_1-2b_2-c_0-8c_1-21c_2)x^3+(3b_0+4b_1-15b_2-8c_0-21c_1-18c_2)x^2+(10b_0-4b_1-12b_2-21c_0-18c_1)x+(7b_0-6b_1-18c_0+1)$

This system solves to $\begin{cases}B=\frac 94x^2+\frac{25}{2}x+17\\C=\frac 94x+\frac 52\end{cases}$

And the formula says :

$$\int \frac AD\mathop{dx}=\frac{B}{D^-}+\int\frac{C}{D^*}\mathop{dx}=\frac{9x^2+50x+68}{4(x+2)(x+3)^2}+\int\frac{9x+10}{4(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)}\mathop{dx}$$

The last part is still solved by partial fraction decomposition, but is much simpler:

$\int=-\frac{17}8\ln(x+3)+2\ln(x+2)+\frac 18\ln(x+1)$

Answer (score 1):

In order to determine the partial fraction decomposition of $$f(x) = \frac{1}{(x+1)(x+2)^2(x+3)^3} = \frac{A_1}{x+1} + \frac{B_1}{x+2} + \frac{B_2}{(x+2)^2} + \frac{C_1}{x+3} + \frac{C_2}{(x+3)^2} + \frac{C_3}{(x+3)^3}$$ we can proceed as follows:

$$A_1 = \lim\limits_{x\to -1} (x+1)f(x) = \lim\limits_{x\to -1} \frac{1}{(x+2)^2(x+3)^3} = \frac{1}{8}$$

$$B_2 = \lim\limits_{x\to -2} (x+2)^2f(x) = \lim\limits_{x\to -2} \frac{1}{(x+1)(x+3)^3} = -1$$

$$C_3 = \lim\limits_{x\to -3} (x+3)^3f(x) = \lim\limits_{x\to -3} \frac{1}{(x+1)(x+2)^2} = -\frac{1}{2}$$

$$B_1 = \lim\limits_{x\to -2} (x+2)\left[f(x) - \frac{B_2}{(x+2)^2}\right] = \lim\limits_{x\to -2} \frac{1}{x+2}\left[(x+2)^2f(x)-B_2\right] $$ $$ = \lim\limits_{x\to -2} \frac{1}{x+2}\left[\frac{1}{(x+1)(x+3)^3}+1\right] = -\lim\limits_{x\to -2}\frac{1+(x+1)(x+3)^3}{x+2} $$ $$ = -\lim\limits_{x\to -2} \left[(x+3)^3 + 3(x+1)(x+3)^2\right] = 2 \text{ (by l'Hopital's rule)}$$

$$C_2 = \lim\limits_{x\to -3} (x+3)^2\left[f(x) - \frac{C_3}{(x+3)^3}\right] = \lim\limits_{x\to -3} \frac{1}{x+3}\left[(x+3)^3f(x) - C_3\right]$$ $$ = \lim\limits_{x\to -3}\frac{1}{x+3}\left[\frac{1}{(x+1)(x+2)^2} + \frac{1}{2}\right] = -\frac{1}{2}\lim\limits_{x\to -3}\frac{\frac{1}{2}(x+1)(x+2)^2+1}{x+3}$$ $$ = -\frac{1}{2}\lim\limits_{x\to -3}\left[\frac{1}{2}(x+2)^2 + (x+1)(x+2)\right] = -\frac{5}{4} \text{ (by l'Hopital's rule)}$$

$$C_1 = \lim\limits_{x\to -3} (x+3)\left[f(x) - \frac{C_2}{(x+3)^2} - \frac{C_1}{(x+3)^3}\right] = \frac{1}{(x+3)^2}\left[(x+3)^3f(x) - C_2(x+3) - C_3\right]$$ $$ = \lim\limits_{x\to -3} \frac{1}{(x+3)^2}\left[\frac{1}{(x+1)(x+2)^2}+\frac{5}{4}(x+3)+\frac{1}{2}\right] $$ $$ = -\frac{1}{2}\lim\limits_{x\to -3}\frac{\frac{5}{4}(x+1)(x+2)^2(x+3)+\frac{1}{2}(x+1)(x+2)^2+1}{(x+3)^2} $$ $$ = -\frac{1}{4}\lim\limits_{x\to -3} \frac{\mathrm{d}^2}{\mathrm{d}x^2}\left[\frac{5}{4}(x+1)(x+2)^2(x+3)+\frac{1}{2}(x+1)(x+2)^2+1\right] \text{ (by l'Hopital's rule twice)}$$ $$ = -\frac{17}{8}$$

The last one is more annoying to calculate unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

$$I=\int\frac{1}{(x+1)(x+2)^2(x+3)^3}dx$$
If you use the recommendation suggested by other users ($u=x+2$) you get:
$$I=\int\frac{1}{(u-1)u^2(u+1)^3}du$$
It is clear that we need to use partial fractions and we can say that it will be of the form:
$$\frac{1}{(u-1)u^2(u+1)^3}=\frac{A}{(u-1)}+\frac{B}{u^2}+\frac{C}{u}+\frac{D}{(u+1)^3}+\frac{E}{(u+1)^2}+\frac{F}{(u+1)}\tag{1}$$
multiplying by both the denominator of the LHS on both sides gives:
$$1=Au^2(u+1)^3+B(u-1)(u+1)^3+C(u-1)u(u+1)^3+D(u-1)u^2+E(u-1)u^2(u+1)+F(u-1)u^2(u+1)^2$$
This gives us the following simultaneous equations:
$$1A+0B+1C+0D+0E+1F=0\tag{2.1}$$
$$3A+1B+2C+0D+1E+1F=0\tag{2.2}$$
$$3A+2B+0C+1D+0E-1F=0\tag{2.3}$$
$$1A+0B-2C-1D-1E-1F=0\tag{2.4}$$
$$0A-2B-1C+0D+0E+0F=0\tag{2.5}$$
$$0A-1B+0C+0D+0E+0F=1\tag{2.6}$$
From $(2.6)$ we can see that $B=-1$ and so our equations can be transformed and put in matrix form:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1&1&0&0&1\\
3&2&0&1&1\\
3&0&1&0&-1\\
1&-2&-1&-1&-1\\
0&-1&0&0&0
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}A\\C\\D\\E\\F\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\2\\0\\2\end{pmatrix}\tag{3}$$
Using a solving method like **Gauss Jordan Elimination** we can obtain:
$$\begin{pmatrix}A\\B\\C\\D\\E\\F\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0.625\\-1\\-2\\1.5\\1.75\\1.375\end{pmatrix}\tag{4}$$
Now we can start on the integrals, I will subscript each part to show what it refers to:
$$I_a=\int\frac{A}{u-1}du=A\ln|u-1|\tag{a}$$
$$I_b=\int\frac{B}{u^2}du=B\int u^{-2}du=-\frac Bu\tag{b}$$
$$I_c=\int\frac Cudu=C\ln|u|\tag{c}$$
$$I_d=\int\frac{D}{(u+1)^3}du=D\int v^{-3}dv=-\frac{D}{2}v^{-2}=-\frac{D}{2(u+1)^2}\tag{d}$$
$$I_e=\int\frac{E}{(u+1)^2}du=E\int v^{-2}dv=-\frac{E}{(u+1)}\tag{e}$$
$$I_f=\int\frac{F}{u+1}du=F\ln|u+1|\tag{f}$$
adding all of these together gives:
$$I=A\ln|u-1|-\frac Bu+C\ln|u|-\frac{D}{2(u+1)^2}-\frac{E}{u+1}+F\ln|u+1|\tag{5}$$
Back-substituting $u$ for $x$ gives:
$$I=A\ln|x+1|-\frac {B}{x+2}+C\ln|x+2|-\frac{D}{2(x+3)^2}-\frac{E}{x+3}+F\ln|x+3|\tag{6}$$
and now finally putting in our values for the letters:
$$I=\frac{5}{8}\ln|x+1|+\frac {1}{x+2}-2\ln|x+2|-\frac{3}{4(x+3)^2}-\frac{7}{4(x+3)}+\frac{11}{8}\ln|x+3|+C_1\tag{7}$$

**EDIT**: I believe there is an error somewhere in calculating the values so I will leave the original answer above for the process but go through what I believe is the correct steps for the constants.

$$A+C+F=0$$
$$3A+B+2C+E+F=0$$
$$3A+2B+D-F=0$$
$$A-2C-D-E-F=0$$
$$-2B-C=0$$
$$-B=1$$ 
From this we can see that $B=-1$ and easily work out that $C=-2B=2$ which allows us to simplify the matrix to:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0&1\\
3&0&1&1\\
3&1&0&-1\\
1&-1&-1&-1
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}A\\D\\E\\F\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}-2\\-3\\-4\\4\end{pmatrix}\tag{8}$$
Which using gaussian elimination I have reduced to:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0&1\\
0&4&3&2\\
0&0&2&4\\
0&0&0&-8\\
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}A\\D\\E\\F\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}-2\\-16\\-5\\11\end{pmatrix}\tag{9}$$
Which I found to give:
$$\begin{pmatrix}A\\B\\C\\D\\E\\F\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}-5/8\\-1\\2\\-7/2\\1/4\\-11/8\end{pmatrix}\tag{10}$$

Comment: I believe I have made a mistake somewhere as going through a second time gives different values for $A,B,C,D,E,F$